# Как сделать чтобы набор в input начинался не с начала?

Tags: html, css

Как сделать чтобы набор текста в `input` начинался не с начала, а с середины?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`text-align: center`

```css
input {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<input type="text">
```